# Website for budget hotels or hostels for Switzerland

Tags: budget, online-resources, hotels, switzerland, hostels

I am planning to visit Switzerland at the end of the month.  My preferred places of travel are Geneva or Bern.  Could you suggest some online booking websites for budget hotels or hostels?

Comment: Would you consider this question to cover yours? : [Hostel accommodation in Geneva](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/1925/101)

Comment: Have you already tried things like booking.com or hostelworld.com and all the other sites and couldn't find a good accommodation?

Comment: Normally,  I book my accommodation through  hostelworld.com, but  my  last  two journey  withthru  hostelworld was horrible.

Comment: This is a very old question, but in the case of Geneva, going across the border to France may yield cheaper alternatives, the further from Switzerland the cheaper, probably.

Answer (score 10):

First of all, Switzerland is very very expensive, especially accommodation. It will be difficult to even find hostels or similar things below 40-50 Swiss francs per night. As I already mentioned in the comments, you can find hotels in Geneva and Berne and all other Swiss cities on major booking sites, such as [`booking.com`](http://www.booking.com) or [`hostelworld.com`](http://www.hostelworld.com)

However, if you're looking for dedicated Swiss accommodation sites, you will probably find these sites useful:

An overview of campsites, hotels, hostels, BnBs, etc in the whole of Switzerland:
[`myswitzerland.com`](http://www.myswitzerland.com/en/accommodation.html)

BnBs in the whole of Switzerland:
[`bnb.ch`](http://www.bnb.ch/)

Accommodation especially for the region around Geneva and Lake Geneva:
[`lake-geneva-region.ch`](http://www.lake-geneva-region.ch/en/)

An overview of Swiss hostels:
[`swissbackpackers.ch`](http://www.swissbackpackers.ch/)

The official homepage of Bern with a dedicated accommodation section:
[`berne.ch`](http://www.berne.ch/de/)

The official homepage of Geneva with a dedicated accommodation section:
[`geneve-tourisme.ch`](http://www.geneve-tourisme.ch/?rubrique=0000000001)

If you already know the names of the hostels / hotels you want to stay in, it is also always worth checking their own websites or calling them to check if they have any special offers at the moment. Almost all people in this industry speak English in Switzerland.

Answer (score 4):

I have stayed in a hostel in Switzerland. To echo other people, Switzerland is very expensive.

I have found the Tourist Information Offices to be helpful. You could just turn up and ask them about hostels in their town.

Answer (score 1):

I stayed at Bern Backpackers Hostel Glocke, excellent location, clean. I did enjoy, the only downside was a bit of street noise.

If you're visiting other places in the Canton of Bern, you could look at [travelaholics.com](http://www.travelaholics.com/accommodation/switzerland/berne/d1484/)